# Reloading parse data after dismissing modal view controller

Tags: uitableview, parse-platform, uinavigationcontroller, modalviewcontroller

I am stuck on trying to figure how to reload objects from parse after I dismiss a modal view. Typically I can just call [self loadObjects] but dont know how to call this immediately after the model view is dismissed. The modal view is used to post data to parse, I want the data to be loaded in the tableview once the modal view is dismissed.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you always want to reload after the modal is dismissed, then I would recommend moving using `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion` to dismiss your modal and calling `[self loadObjects]` inside the completion block

Comment: I understand what you are saying but when you present a modal view controller, the parent view never leaves. Therefore, after dismissing the modal view, the viewDidLoad will not be called since it has already been loaded.

Comment: My apologies - got carried away and though Push instead of Modal. Updated answer :)